# What species of arthropod is in this picture?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I've found exactly one of these, dead, on my kitchen floor most mornings this past week.

It looks like a large flea, is about 1 cm long (picture compares it to a British 10 pence coin, approx. 24.5 mm in diameter) and 2 mm thick with a laterally flattened body.

I believe it to be of the order Siphonaptera, but am unsure as to what exactly it is.

Can anybody identify the exact species of this arthropod?

If it helps, I live in the South-West of the UK.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like a flea, to me. Fleas have saliently long hindlegs.

Comment: Don't worry, it is not a flea, nor is it an insect. Looks like a crustacean to me (like a pillbug), but I am not sure of the species.

Comment: This is an amphipod, or "scud" (think of a pillbug that's flattened side-to-side rather than top-to-bottom); they're usually aquatic.  Getting past that point will probably be difficult (impossible for me, as I don't know the British fauna of the group).